# Remove Duplicates from 3 deep nested list - python - sympy

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Im working with sympy and I have a list with some duplicates (the order doesn't matter, I still consider them duplicates) and Im looking for a way to remove them.

The list is as fallows,

```
A=[[[m, b], [f, g]],
   [[g, h], [f, b]],
   [[f, g], [m, b]]]
```

I would consider `[[m, b], [f, g]]` and `[[f, g], [m, b]]` as the same and am trying to figure out a way to to make a list with them removed. It would look like this,

```
B=[[[m, b], [f, g]],
   [[g, h], [f, b]]].
```

It dosnt matter which of the duplicate it keeps, so long as only 1 remains.

Ive tried using the set function but it gives out 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' error and Im not sure sure. Any input or advice is apprecaited.

Comment: List A does not have proper closing brackets, can you fix it?

Comment: I have update my answer now check again.

Comment: @Asiv what happen, my answer doesn't solve your problem ?

Comment: No it worked sorry that was an accident

Comment: No problem @Asiv :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [[['m', 'b'], ['f', 'g']], [['g', 'h'], ['f', 'b']], [['f', 'g'], ['m', 'b']], [['l', 'k'], ['d', 'c']]]
B = []
C = []
for i in A:
    for j in i:
        if j not in B:
            B = B + [j]

c = 0
c1 = 1
counter = int(len(B) / 2)
for k in range(counter):
    C.append([B[k+c], B[k+c1]])
    c = c + 1
    c1 = c + 1
print(B)
print(C)
```

[image: This is an Output]

Comment: Hey this is not exactly doing what I'd like it to. The output ends up being [['m', 'b'], ['f', 'g'], ['g', 'h'], ['f', 'b']], but ideally I'd like to keep the nested elements togather as such, [[['m', 'b'], ['f', 'g']],[ ['g', 'h'], ['f', 'b']]]

Comment: sorry please elaborate

Comment: i didn't understood what you are trying to say

Comment: The output leaves the list flattened and I'd still like the[ [['m', 'b'], ['f', 'g']]] to be nested together, rather then as separate elements in the list

Comment: @Asiv now check it gives exactly what you want